# Add vector to each row of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a vector `to_add` which looks like this:

```
> to_add
  X0 X3 X6 X9 X12 X18 X21
1  6  0  4  1   5   3   6
```

I'd like to add it to every row of my dataframe data, which looks like this:

```
> head(data)
                         X0 X3 X6 X9 X12 X18 X21
chr5_89951600_89954799   18 26 19 22  29  30  23
chr16_70874600_70876999  15 26 25 14  18  23  16
chr2_51953000_51955199    7 26  7 14  26  17  33
chr3_143120600_143123799 25 40 35 23  25  28  31
chr15_34771400_34774599  27 42 31 21  24  15  34
chr2_13077000_13083999   36 73 52 48  73  54  53
```

How do I do this efficiently? I doubt writing a loop is the cleverest way...

Unfortunately, `data + to_add` does not work, even though `data + 1` does...

And `data + as.numeric(to_add)`

did not do what I wanted- the results are wrong!

```
> head(data + as.numeric(to_add))
                         X0 X3 X6 X9 X12 X18 X21
chr5_89951600_89954799   24 32 25 28  35  36  29
chr16_70874600_70876999  15 26 25 14  18  23  16
chr2_51953000_51955199   11 30 11 18  30  21  37
chr3_143120600_143123799 26 41 36 24  26  29  32
chr15_34771400_34774599  32 47 36 26  29  20  39
chr2_13077000_13083999   39 76 55 51  76  57  56
```

Ps. I'm doing this to make all the column medians the same, so a simpler way of making the column medians the same than just adding the difference between the column median and the column with the max median value would be appreciated.

Comment: One idea: `data.frame(Map("+",data,to_add),row.names=rownames(data))` - don't have time to post an answer, but that works I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a specific function for this purpose:

```
sweep(data, 2, to_add, "+")
                         X0 X3 X6 X9 X12 X18 X21
chr5_89951600_89954799   24 26 23 23  34  33  29
chr16_70874600_70876999  21 26 29 15  23  26  22
chr2_51953000_51955199   13 26 11 15  31  20  39
chr3_143120600_143123799 31 40 39 24  30  31  37
chr15_34771400_34774599  33 42 35 22  29  18  40
chr2_13077000_13083999   42 73 56 49  78  57  59
```

It applies a particular function across all items of a "margin" using the values in the "statistic". It's the `mean` of that margin (and here you want columns) by default, but it can be any vector of the same length as the margin.

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
data + to_add[col(data)]
#                         X0 X3 X6 X9 X12 X18 X21
#chr5_89951600_89954799   24 26 23 23  34  33  29
#chr16_70874600_70876999  21 26 29 15  23  26  22
#chr2_51953000_51955199   13 26 11 15  31  20  39
#chr3_143120600_143123799 31 40 39 24  30  31  37
#chr15_34771400_34774599  33 42 35 22  29  18  40
#chr2_13077000_13083999   42 73 56 49  78  57  59
```

Comment: That's pretty slick/elegant/ganz raffiniert ... 'kewl' in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, thelatemail!

`result <- data.frame(Map("+",data,to_add),row.names=rownames(data))`

```
> head(result)
                         X0 X3 X6 X9 X12 X18 X21
chr5_89951600_89954799   24 26 23 23  34  33  29
chr16_70874600_70876999  21 26 29 15  23  26  22
chr2_51953000_51955199   13 26 11 15  31  20  39
chr3_143120600_143123799 31 40 39 24  30  31  37
chr15_34771400_34774599  33 42 35 22  29  18  40
chr2_13077000_13083999   42 73 56 49  78  57  59
```

If you decide to add this as an answer later I will delete mine and accept yours, thelatemail.